# Splitting String based on occurrence

Tags: java

I want to split a String based on first occurrence but when I try to use String.split("\_",1) - It gives me arrayOutOfBounds Exception

```
array[0] = "this_first";
array[1] = "Not_first";
array[2] = "Maybe_Like_this";
array[3] = "This_is_definitely_it";

for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        tmparr = array[i].split("\\_");
        firstWord = tmparr[0];
        System.out.println(firstWord);
        tempString = tmparr[1];
```

I want just the first word in tmparr[0] and rest all in tmparr[1].
Please advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `limit` parameter for [`String#split(String, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) is defined a little bit strangely.  Go back and read the Javadoc, particularly the paragraph starting "The limit parameter...".

TL;DR: What you probably need is this:

```
tmparr = array[i].split("_", 2);
```

(Backslash also not required)